# Python JSON serialize excluding certain fields

Tags: python, json, serialization

**Summary**

I have a Python object hierarchy I want to serialize using JSON (just via https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html, not using any extra third-party library).  I want to *exclude* certain fields/properties/sub-objects.  I'm finding it surprisingly difficult to find a simple answer as to how to achieve this?

**Example**

I'll have a derived class instance ending up like this:

```
class MyItemClass(BaseItemClass):
    self.saveThisProperty = 999
    self.dontSaveThisProperty = "Something"
    self.saveThisObject = ObjectType1()
    self.dontSaveThisObject = ObjectType2()
```

If I were serializing to XML, I would want it to look like

```
<MyItemClass>
    <saveThisProperty>999</saveThisProperty>
    <saveThisObject>
        ...
    </saveThisObject>
</MyItemClass>
```

Note that I only serialize *certain* properties/sub-objects, and I do *not* want to serialize the whole `BaseItemClass` from which my class instance is derived.

In XML I'm fine. I know how to output bits of XML as I go along for what I do want, either to a temporary in-memory document which I save at the end or by outputting individual nodes/elements to the stream incrementally. I don't have to serialize everything. E.g.

```
xmlStream.writeStartElement("MyItemClass")
    xmlStream.writeElementWithValue("saveThisProperty", 999)
    xmlStream.writeStartElement("saveThisObject")
        ...
    xmlStream.writeEndElement("saveThisObject")
xmlStream.writeEndElement("MyItemClass")
```

For JSON I can't do this, can I?  Do I *have to* create some new, "standalone" object hierarchy (with no derivations from `BaseClass`) by copying just the properties/sub-objects I want into it and then JSON serialize that?

I did see there is `json.dump(default = ...)`, but that says:

> If specified, default should be a function that gets called for objects that can’t otherwise be serialized. It should return a JSON encodable version of the object

However, it is not that the original objects *cannot* be serialized by default Python->JSON, it is that I do not *want* that default, serialize-everything behaviour, I want my "selective" one.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the json docs: user-defined _can't_ be serialised by default; you need to provide an implementation for `default` that can serialise them, and that implementation can do whatever you want, as long as the result can be serialised.

Comment: Thank you.  And how do you write one single `default` function for this?  My hierarchy will be deep and involve many object classes at various levels. The top level `dump()` call will not have a function/class available which could possibly know about the classes it will meet, the encoding needs to be delegated to each class as it is encountered...?

Comment: You could give each class a `serialise` method that produces the required output, and have `default` call `obj.serialise()` on each object it encounters, or use a third party tool like that mentioned in the answer, or marshmallow etc.

Comment: @snakecharmerb We are nearly there!  That is what I am doing to get going at present.  The question is: do I (a) do a pass through the tree calling `serialise()` to build a new "shadow, serialisable" single object tree, which is then passed to `json.dump()` at the end, or (b) does each object's `serialise()` method return nothing and instead write the serialisation to the stream as it goes, in which case how?

Comment: Each object's `serialise` method should return a `dict`.  `json.dumps` will visit all the objects in your object graph and attempt to serialise them, calling `default` if it doesn't know how to serialise the object.  You can write `default` so that calling `serialise`  is a catchall, i.e. no `isinstance` check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three solutions for your situation:

**Solution 1:**
Use [Pykson](https://github.com/sinarezaei/pykson) third party library and define the fields you want to be serialized as pykson fields.

Sample:

```
class MyItemClass(pykson.JsonObject):
    saved_property = pykson.IntegerField()

my_object = MyItemClass(saved_property=1, accept_unknown=True)
my_object.unsaved_property = 2
pykson.Pykson().to_json(my_object)
```

disclaimer: I am developer of pykson library.

**Solution 2:**
The second solution is to use a wrapper class with custom default deserializer.

```
class ObjectWrapper:
    def __init__(self, value, should_serialize=False)
        self.value = value
        self.should_serialize = should_serialize

def default_handler(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, ObjectWrapper):
        if obj.should_serialize:
            return obj.value
        else:
            return None
    else:
        raise TypeError

json.dump(default=default_handler)
```

**Solution 3:**
It might be a bad idea but if you have a in case of deep hierarchy, you can also add a function to allc classes which will be serialized and use this function to get a dictionary and easily convert the dictionary to json.

```
class MyChildClass:
     def __init__(self, serialized_property, not_serialized_property):
        self.serialized_property = serialized_property
        self.not_serialized_property = not_serialized_property

     def to_dict(self):
        # only add serialized property here
        return {
            "serialized_property": self.serialized_property
        }

class MyParentClass:
    def __init__(self, child_property, some_other_property):
        self.child_property = child_property
        self.some_other_property = some_other_property

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'child_property': self.child_property.to_dict(),
            'some_other_property': self.some_other_property
        }

my_child_object = MyChildClass(serialized_property=1, not_serialized_property=2)
my_parent_object = MyParentClass(child_property=my_child_object, some_other_property='some string here')
json.dumps(my_parent_object.to_dict())
```

Or you can achieve same result using default handler:

```
class MyChildClass:
     def __init__(self, serialized_property, not_serialized_property):
        self.serialized_property = serialized_property
        self.not_serialized_property = not_serialized_property

     def to_dict(self):
        # only add serialized property here
        return {
            "serialized_property": self.serialized_property
        }

class MyParentClass:
    def __init__(self, child_property, some_other_property):
        self.child_property = child_property
        self.some_other_property = some_other_property

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'child_property': self.child_property,
            'some_other_property': self.some_other_property
        }

def handle_default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, MyChildClass):
        return obj.to_dict()
    elif isinstance(obj, MyParentClass):
        return obj.to_dict()
    return None

my_child_object = MyChildClass(serialized_property=1, not_serialized_property=2)
my_parent_object = MyParentClass(child_property=my_child_object, some_other_property='some string here')
json.dumps(my_parent_object, default=handle_default)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm afraid I don't want to use anyone's library, so would need Solution #2.  I don't understand how you intend it to be used.  And struggling on `dump(default=function)` vs `dump(cls=alternative_JSONEncoder)`.  My hierarchy will be deep and involve many object classes at various levels.  The top level `dump()` call will not have a function/class available which could possibly know about the classes it will meet, the encoding needs to be delegated to each class as it is encountered...?

Comment: @JonBrave Check my edit, maybe it helps if you have a limited number of predefined class types.

Comment: Also there might be another solution to use specific names for not serialized variables and skip those names. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55151894/5528269

Comment: OK, this is like what I am doing now.  Your `to_dict()` is called first in a pass to build a "shadow, serializable" object hierarchy, then finally a single call the `json.dump()` of that hierarchy is made.  It does not write to the serialization stream as it goes.  I cannot have some single `handle_default` method in a module as it would not even know what classes it will encounter in order to write `isinstance(obj, SomeClass)`, the classes will be defined all over the place in various modules.  I am using `if hasattr(obj, "to_dict"): return obj.to_dict()` to make it generic.

Answer (score 5):

I am the OP.  I post here for clarity what I have ended up using for my case.

I have marked @Sina Rezaei's post in this thread as the Accepted Solution, since that (the last section in his post) and @snakechamerb's comments inspired me to understand what is required.

The outline of my soluton looks like:

```
class ModelScene(QGraphicsScene):

  # Serialize whole scene to JSON into stream
  def json_serialize(self, stream) -> None:
    # Get `json.dump()` to call `ModelScene.json_serialize_dump_obj()` on every object to be serialized
    json.dump(self, stream, indent=4, default=ModelScene.json_serialize_dump_obj)

  # Static method to be called from `json.dump(default=ModelScene.json_serialize_dump_obj)`
  # This method is called on every object to be dumped/serialized
  @staticmethod
  def json_serialize_dump_obj(obj):
    # if object has a `json_dump_obj()` method call that...
    if hasattr(obj, "json_dump_obj"):
      return obj.json_dump_obj()
    # ...else just allow the default JSON serialization
    return obj

  # Return dict object suitable for serialization via JSON.dump()
  # This one is in `ModelScene(QGraphicsScene)` class
  def json_dump_obj(self) -> dict:
    return {
      "_classname_": self.__class__.__name__,
      "node_data": self.node_data
      }

class CanvasModelData(QAbstractListModel):

  # Return dict object suitable for serialization via JSON.dump()
  # This one is class CanvasModelData(QAbstractListModel)
  def json_dump_obj(self) -> dict:
    _data = {}
    for key, value in self._data.items():
      _data[key] = value
    return {
      "_classname_": self.__class__.__name__,
      "data_type": self.data_type,
      "_data": _data
      }
```

- Every "complex" class defines a `def json_dump_obj(self) -> dict:` method.
- That method returns just the properties/sub-objects wanted in the serialization.
- The top-level `json.dump(self, stream, default=ModelScene.json_serialize_dump_obj)` causes every node visited to be incrementally serialized to stream, via static method `ModelScene.json_serialize_dump_obj`. And that calls my `obj.json_dump_obj()` if available, else default JSON serialization of basic object type.

Interestingly, I came across someone with the same concerns as me. From **What is the difference between json.dump() and json.dumps() in python?**, solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57087055/489865:

> In memory usage and speed.
>
> When you call `jsonstr = json.dumps(mydata)` it first creates a full
>   copy of your data in memory and only then you `file.write(jsonstr)` it
>   to disk. So this is a faster method but can be a problem if you have a
>   big piece of data to save.
>
> When you call `json.dump(mydata, file)` -- without `'s'`, new memory is
>   not used, as the data is dumped by chunks. But the whole process is
>   about 2 times slower.
>
> Source: I checked the source code of `json.dump()` and `json.dumps()` and
>   also tested both the variants measuring the time with `time.time()` and
>   watching the memory usage in htop.